# how to get an image from flask api in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, flask, fetch-api

I'm sending an image using flask to react native, I get "200 OK" if I used postman and I also see the image, but when I'm using react native to get the image and display it on the screen I get the "error Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0."

here's the code:

```
  fetch("http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/echo", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  })
})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(responseJson => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(responseJson));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
};
```

I don't know what exactly should I write in .then(), I've tried couple of solutions I found on the internet, but none of them worked.

here's the flask code:

```
@app.route('/api/echo', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
def add():
  while(True):
    data = request.get_json()
    img = plt.imread('mapflask.png')
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.scatter(100, 20, s=30, c='red', marker='o')
    plt.scatter(30, 40, s=30, c='blue', marker='o')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig("test100.png", transparent=True,
                bbox_inches='tight', dpi=150)

    filename = 'test100.png'
    return send_file(filename, mimetype='image/jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an image as a response and accepting `application/json` in response.

you should do something like this:-

```
var image
  fetch("http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/echo", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  })
})
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(images => {
      // Then create a local URL for that image and print it 
      image = URL.createObjectURL(images)
      console.log(image)
  })  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
};
```

Comment: it says "Cannot create URL for blob!"